# No crear una tabla en BD con base al modelo en MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET MVC y necesito hacer que me muestre un listado de los usuarios registrados, aunque no quiero que se guarden en la base de datos, sino obtenerlos del modelo `RegisterViewModel` que se creó automáticamente al crear el proyecto, tengo un modelo llamado `UserPermission` en el que solamente tengo el objeto para realizar el listado, y lo puse como `PrimaryKey`:

```
public class UserPermission  
{
    [Key]
    public String UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

En mi controlador tengo lo siguiente:

```
public class UserPermissionsController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: UserPermissions
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var Users = db.Users;
        List<UserPermission> UserPermissions = new List<UserPermission>();
        foreach (var User in Users)
        {
            UserPermission permissions = new UserPermission();
            permissions.User = User;
            permissions.UserId = User.Id;
            UserPermissions.Add(permissions);
        }
        return View(UserPermissions);
    }
}
```

El cual muestra el listado de los usuarios en el `Index`:

```
@model SigaWeb.Models.IndexPaginatorViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Crear nuevo", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserPermissions[0].User.Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserPermissions[0].User.UserName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.UserPermissions) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.UserId }) |
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.UserId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.UserId })*@
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
@{Html.RenderPartial("_paginator", Model);}
```

Bueno, el caso es que yo no quiero guardar nada en la base de datos, simplemente me serviría para mostrar, pero al momento de agregarle el `[Key]` a mi modelo, y querer ejecutarlo me pide realizar una migración lo cual no quiero hacerlo.

Hay alguna forma de que pueda mostrarlo sin que se guarde en la base de datos, y si la hay, ¿me podrían decir cómo?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usa la palabra `virtual` esta creando una relación uno a muchos entre las clases, lo que genera un cambio en el modelo y por eso le sale el mensaje de ejecutar la migración. Simplemente remueva la palabra virtual en la declaración de la clase UserPermission así:

```
public class UserPermission  
{
    [Key]
    public String UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: mira el [tour] para saber como funcionamos.. gracias por la respuesta!